# ANT server target

Tags: deployment, ant

Are the only possible values of SF.SERVERURL in an SF ANT scenario either "login.salesforce.com" or "test.salesforce.com" ?

How do you deploy to a production org if "my domain" is used and logins from "login.salesforce.com" are prevented?

I've tried several ways of specifying the "mydomain" address in the SERVERURL field and keep getting the message:

*Error: {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}INVALID_SESSION_ID - INVALID_SES
SION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session*

My ANT setup worked fine deploying to production until we were forced to disable logins from login.salesforce.com by the way - both deploys and retrievals are now broken....

Comment: Check your login history and make sure it actually shows a restricted domain failure.

Comment: login history says the connection was successful, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved.  Evidently there was a problem when our production Org was migrated to a new Pod - SF support mentioned they were making patches to fix reported problems on the new pod (NA21) - presumably one of those patches fixed this error and ANT is working now as before for us.